# X-Cart 5 on WAMP local server - Import by CSV throws Internal Service Error

Tags: wamp, x-cart

I am trying to build a store on my local machine. I am able to import categories.csv, but when I try to import products.csv I get an Internal Server Error during initialization. My first attempt had thousands of products, but even after I cut it down to 100 I still get the same result. What do I need to fix/change to get the import to work?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your log files?
You can check them in <X-Cart>/var/log/2018/03/ directory.

Comment: This is what it shows in the php_errors.log:

Error (code: 0): Unrecognized field: attribute_option
Server API: apache2handler;
Request method: POST;
URI: /admin.php?target=event_task&action=run&event=import;

Comment: The problem might look like the attribute entities do not exist in X-Cart, but it is very unlikely, unless you removed them manually. I would suggest contacting our support team via support@x-cart.com and asking them to look into the problem.